# Vector2 : Class or Struct?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want a simple Vector2 class/struct with float x and y and a couple methods.
I'm still trying to wrap my head around the differences but can't quite get it yet
I know it's usually done with structs, but i want to update a large 2D array of Vector2 every frame, would that make a class better than a struct ?
First post here by the way, and thanks for all replies in advance !

Comment: I vote **struct**

Comment: What I don't understand is that you give the Unity3D tag for your question. There is already a Vector2/3/4 struct in the engine so no need to create your own.

Comment: I thought that constant updating makes a class better than a struct so that i should make a new Vector2 class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> would that make a class better than a struct

for this operation, neither would be specifically any better or worse; however, having a lot of long-lived objects means you're likely to hit GC glitches. The fact that it  is a "large 2D array" means that you can also potentially save a significant  amount  of overhead (object headers) by using structs.

Comment: Dear Sir! **you can also potentially save a significant amount of overhead (object headers) by using structs** this is too much information for me to digest. can you explain it a bit more.

Comment: It's too much for me to digest too, but after some googling i kinda have an idea.
so if i understood it correctly, is garbage collecting a struct more expensive than collecting a primitive type ? Would that make 2 arrays of float easier for the GC ? but wouldn't that also double the amount of overhead ? Which one should i favor ? Also they say don't use a struct unless it's immutable. isn't updating every frame considered "mutability" ?Thanks for the reply

Comment: @UmairM every instance of a `class` is an **object**. An object is allocated space on the heap consisting of an *object header* plus the actual data. A value-type is allocated *as part of something else*, and does not have an object header - the type is implied via the thing that owns it. In the case of an array, the type is implied *by the type of the array*. When you have thousands or millions of small pieces of data, this difference starts  to add up.

Comment: One very important thing to add to this answer is that `structs` are pass by `value` not `reference`. If you want to pass a **heavy** `struct` with data such as mesh info and mesh uv coordinates to another function, use the `ref` keyword. Do this especially in Unity or you will be wondering while things are slow. You don't have to do this for a `class`.

Comment: @Programmer fun fact: reference-types (classes) are *also* "pass by VA" by default; the tricky thing is *what you are passing* (by value) *is a reference*. References can also be "passed by reference".

Comment: @MarcGravell Wow that actually sounds beautiful ! but why would the compiler need a reference to the reference of a value ??

Comment: That becomes out of topic now. But you would pass a reference to a reference if you want to update it. Consider you have a dog object and you want to make it point to an entirely different dog object. If you pass to a method, you are copying the reference value so changing this would only affect within the method. Passing a ref to a ref you are affecting inside the method AND the outside reference as well. So confusing....

Comment: Only someone already understanding the concept can understand my previous comment...

Comment: Actually it's quite clear and useful, like if i want to edit the dog itself it will be edited without the ref keyword because i'm pointing at it, but if i assign the dog object to a different dog, or in other words if i edit the reference itself, it will not keep the reference outside the method, so it will come out of the method as the old dog, Nice ! yet i didn't get the answer for "isn't constant updating the same as mutability ?"

Comment: @Hadi that depends; you can still do a lot with immutable structs - especially via `ref` or in an array - but instead of doing  `val.X += 3` you might do `val = new Whatever(val.X + 3, val.Y);` - so you're not mutating the struct as such, but you are changing the value by replacing everything at once. Both mutable and immutable structs have uses, but it is very good advice that structs should be immutable unless you understand fully what the implications are and why you're doing it; mutable structs are very easy to get wrong!

Comment: Thank you very much ! at first i thought that assigning a new value is considered mutating and will have the "evil" results, makes much more sense now